# CodedUI Test HtmlButton disabled in JS

Tags: angularjs, coded-ui-tests

I'm having an issue in Coded UI where a HTMLButton is disabled until the user selects an item in a list box. At which point the button is enabled via javascript. The problem I'm having is that the recorder is not picking up the change. When I run the test I get a "ActionNotSupportedOnDisabledControlException". I've tried the WaitForControlEnabled, Find and WaitForCotrolReady methods but nothing seems to work. Is there a way I can make the button enabled in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check control is disabled or not visible.
I have faced same issue where control was hidden under another control, so it was not visible directly.

You can enable button by executing Javascript from your Coded UI test/script.

Javascript Code:

```
document.getElementById<ID>.disabled = false;
document.getElementsByClassName<>.style.visibility='visible';
```

Test/Script Code:

```
this.UIMap.Window.ExecuteScript(<above / your JavaScript>);
```